# How to implement @NamedQuery in Java Web application using JSF and EJB

Tags: java, jsf-2, ejb-3.0

So I am a noob here, I have created Java Web Application in NetBeans created **Entity Classes from Data base** ( lets say I have only one table in data base named **USER** it generated

1. User.java
2. UserController.java
3. UserFacade.java
4. AbstractFacade.java

and than have created JSF pages from entity classes. It generated

1. Create.xhtml
2. Edit.xhtml
3. List.xhtml
4. View.xhtml

In User.java I have

> @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByName", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u
>   WHERE u.name = :name"),

I need up jump on how to inplement this query in my View.xhtml, because I only need to show users by Name not all. Can someone please give me an instruction.

Comment: You forgot to tell at which step exactly you're stucking. Is it creating JSF managed bean? Or is it creating JSF form with input field? Or is it submitting JSF form? Or is it invoking bean action method? Or is it injecting EJB? Or is it invoking EJB method with input as param? Or is it executing named query with input as parameter? Or is it assigning result of EJB as JSF bean property? Or is it presenting result in a JSF table? Etc..etc.. By the way, you'd better not mess around with code generators as long as you're unable to write code off top of head. Otherwise you learn absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said its difficult to know what you want. To "implement the query in View.xhtml" does'nt make sense, since the NamedQuery will return a List of Users, and View.xhtml can only show 1 User.

It would make more sense to use it from List.xhtml, however then it would be easier to use datatable filtering; something like

```
<p:column filterBy="#{item.name}" filterMatchMode="contains">
    <f:facet name="header">
         Name
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
</p:column>
```

*If* you want/need to use the NamedQuery you need to create a method on the EJB ( = UserFacade); something like

```
public List<User> findByName(String name) {
    return em.createNamedQuery("Users.findByName").setParameter("name", name).getResultList();
}
```

How you would want to call this method I don't know, since the requirements are not clear.